# Count number of txt files in a folder and oldest file if number of files greater than 10?

Tags: c, file-io, directory

I'm using the below program to get the number of files in a folder.
I want to delete the oldest file from the folder if the number of files is greater than 10.

```
#include<dirent.h>

int file_count = 0

DIR * dirp;

struct dirent * entry;

dirp = opendir("path");

while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {

    if (entry->d_name!=NULL) {

    file_count++;

   }

}


closedir(dirp);

printf("%d", file_count-2);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can show you how to do that. After writing the code answer your own question.

1. Use Scandir() function to count the no of files in your directory.

   [see this](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/scandir.3.html)
2. write `system(cd /path/to/your/dir/ && ls -t > res.txt)` it will sort all your files using last modification time. You can also sort by date of creation to do that

   [see this.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created)
3. Then read the names of the files one by one from the files skipping starting 11 files one will be your res.txt and store it in `string name="filename"`
4. declare a string like `string cmd="rm -f "`
5. Append the file names to `strcat(cmd,name);` using.
6. write `system(cmd);`

from reading from file to step 4 it should be in a while loop and condition should be `while( !EOF)`